# Can't access to TFS because of exceeding usage of resource 'Concurrency' in namespace 'VSID'

Tags: azure-devops

When I browse to our TFS via Source Control Explorer, an error occurs:

> Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'Concurrency'
> in namespace 'VSID'. For more information on why your request was
> blocked, see the topic "Rate limits" on the Microsoft Web site

Comment: I just got this same error an hour ago...

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you encountered is related to a sudden event on our side. Users visiting Azure DevOps will see a 429 throttled requests like `Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource ...` And as I know this issue has been resolved, please check it.

More details about this event you can check [this link](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/195124854). The issue was fully mitigated from `7/4/2020`. Our engineers will be investigating this further to learn from and reduce the risk of potential recurrences. We apologize for the impact this had on our customers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in the logs for one of our apps that day but now it is working again. Thanks.